# Not consistent Libre Calc formula results

Tags: libreoffice

I used a check formula to check values with the content type `$33,33`

```
=IF(ISTEXT(F9),F9;IF(ISTEXT(E9;E9;""))
```

It would return `$33,33` or `FALSE` if the cells `F9` or `E9` where empty.

But when I replaced the dollar signs to get just the values the formulas went crazy.

They now delivered `TRUE` OR `""` and not cell values as before. How can this be?

I thought changing the formulas to

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(F9),F9;IF(ISNUMBER(E9;E9;""))
```

would do the trick, but it still delivers `TRUE` or `""` and not the values.

And to top the whole thing off - if I do a direct reference to another cell
that is in cell `Q67`, I put `=E9` I do not get the value, only `TRUE`!

Why does LibreOffice Calc not give me the value in `E9` which is `33,33`, but `TRUE`? It does not be behave as expected.

Comment: because you put a boolean value in the cell, so it formated the cell as boolean. you have to clear the cell formating to make it a value.

Comment: This should rather be asked on https://ask.libreoffice.org, I think it's off topic here.

Comment: @dessert Questions about LibreOffice in Ubuntu are on-topic *even* when not Ubuntu-*specific*. The [on-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) and [off-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask) help pages don't support the claim you've made about Ask Ubuntu's scope, and we have [clear strong consensus](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14523) that [such questions are on-topic](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/47). (Even *within* SE, overlapping scopes are [by design](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/14/unix-and-ubuntu-why-both/).) If you want this policy *changed*, feel free to post on [meta].

Comment: I copied and pasted these formulas and they produced an error.  The parentheses in the second ISTEXT/ISNUMBER are not matched correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example, start out with an empty spreadsheet.  Select cells E9 through H12 and go to *Format -> Cells*.  Specify currency and press OK.

[image: format cells]

Now in E9 through F12 enter the following values.

```
E       F
~~~~~~  ~~~~~~
        $44,44
$33,33  

$33,33  $44,44
```

Finally, enter the following formula in H9 and then drag down to H12.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(F9),F9,IF(ISNUMBER(E9),E9,""))
```

The result in column H:

```
$44,44
$33,33

$44,44
```